# VBA Excel error handling when checking if a particular table exists using table name

Tags: excel, vba

There is a thread which almost gives me exactly what i need when checking a sheet for a table using the table name. This is here...
[VBA Excel check if a particular table exist using table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097134/vba-excel-check-if-a-particular-table-exist-using-table-name)

```
TableExists = False
On Error GoTo Skip
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table123").Name = "Table123" Then TableExists = True
Skip:
    On Error GoTo 0
```

If the table does not exist it goes straight to the error handler, this is fine however i have other code in the function that when errors would end up using the same error handler. Because of this i cannot display a specific msgbox stating that the table does not exist.

Is there a way to display a msgbox if the table does not exist, one that doesn't use the same error handler as other parts of the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate function which can check table exists and has nothing to do with a main routine error handler.

```
Function tableExist(Sht As Worksheet, tblName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    tableExist = Sht.ListObjects(tblName).Name = tblName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub test()

    If tableExist(ActiveSheet, "Table1234") Then

    ' write your code here

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That has helped me

Answer (score 0):

The `TableExists` function returns a boolean value, indicating whether the table exists. Based on this, a `MsgBox` could be shown with some relevant info:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    If TableExists("Table1243", ActiveSheet) Then
        MsgBox "Table Exists"
    Else
        MsgBox "Nope!"
    End If

End Sub    

Public Function TableExists(tableName As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo TableExists_Error
    If ws.ListObjects(tableName).Name = vbNullString Then
    End If
    TableExists = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

TableExists_Error:    
    TableExists = False    
End Function
```