# Attempt to create table gives error 1004 after copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook (A) that pulls up another (B), copies values from wb B and pastes values to wb A (no table, no formulas; just data).

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F" & lonTempWBLastRow).Copy shtNewMonth.Range("A1")
```

I then attempt to create a table with:

```
Set NewMonthTable = wbPDRC.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:F" & lonTempWBLastRow), , xlYes)
```

but get error 1004: a table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable, query results, protected cells, or another table. I delete the named range from the sheet so it's not a named range issue. There's no Pivot, query results, protected cells, or table. I even tried to run a loop on unlisting all tables from the sheet but the loop immediately exits as it doesn't see a table on the sheet. I also attempted to run the table code first on wb B then transfer it as a table VS values but I get the same error on that sheet when attempting this way. If I try to make the table in Excel without VBA, the Format As Table dialog box stays put after hitting "OK" a number of times. There is a connection in wb B which I delete via code prior to transferring the data and have verified once it pastes to wb A that the connection is not there. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, that the problem is that the table already exists, thus, it is not ok to make a new one. Try this piece of code, changing "Table1" to the name of your table:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim newTable As Object
    Dim someRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set someRange = .Range("A1:F" & 10)
        If Not TableExists("Table1", .Cells.Parent) Then
            Set newTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, someRange, , xlYes)
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Public Function TableExists(tableName As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo TableExists_Error
    If ws.ListObjects(tableName).Name = vbNullString Then
    End If
    TableExists = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

TableExists_Error:
    TableExists = False

End Function
```

Or simply open a new Excel file and run it. The `A1:F10` range would be formatted.

- [VBA Excel check if a particular table exist using table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097134/vba-excel-check-if-a-particular-table-exist-using-table-name)

Comment: Maybe because I'm a newbie but I tried to incorporate your code and couldn't figure out exactly how to apply it effectively. I ended up creating a new sheet then creating a fake table on it then pasted my data there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Craig - copy and paste my code completely did not work?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I had to create a fake, blank table as soon as the sheet was created then paste the data over to it.